# R: Add "th", "rd" and "nd" to dates

Tags: r

I have some dates, which I can extract the day of the month from:

```
trimws(format(seq.Date(
  from = as.Date("2016-01-01"),
  to = as.Date("2016-10-01"), by = "day"), "%e"))
```

I would like to format the dates with suffixes "th", "rd" or "nd" as appropriate. So, "1st", "2nd", "3rd", etc. Is there an easy way to accomplish this, or will I have to enumerate the rules?

---

I can implement this as a brute force lookup:

```
df_dates = data_frame(
  day = seq.int(31),
  suffix = c(
    "st",
    "nd",
    "rd",
    rep("th", 17),
    "st",
    "nd",
    "rd",
    rep("th", 7),
    "st"
  )
)
```

but a more elegant solution would be welcome.

Comment: `?scales::ordinal`

Comment: @hrbrmstr Make yours an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a tidyverse solution, using the vectorized SQL style if-else function `case_when`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

append_date_suffix <- function(dates){
  dayy <- day(dates)
  suff <- case_when(dayy %in% c(11,12,13) ~ "th",
                    dayy %% 10 == 1 ~ 'st',
                    dayy %% 10 == 2 ~ 'nd',
                    dayy %% 10 == 3 ~'rd',
                    TRUE ~ "th")
  paste0(dayy, suff)
}
```

Testing it using today's date

```
append_date_suffix(as.Date(-10:10, now()))

 [1] "4th"  "5th"  "6th"  "7th"  "8th"  "9th"  "10th" 
 [8] "11th" "12th" "13th" "14th" "15th" "16th" "17th"
[15] "18th" "19th" "20th" "21st" "22nd" "23rd" "24th"
```

As requested, timings:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(scales::ordinal(as.Date(-1000:1000, now())),
               append_date_suffix(as.Date(-1000:1000, now())))

Unit: milliseconds
                                           expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
    scales::ordinal(as.Date(-1000:1000, now())) 45.89437 46.408347 47.316820 46.734974 48.228251 53.14592   100
 append_date_suffix(as.Date(-1000:1000, now()))  1.39770  1.451481  1.549895  1.490646  1.530105  3.52757   100
```

The actual timings requested are below. We're not measuring the speed of `as.Date()` and we need to ensure both methods output the same thing:

```
ads_cw <- function(dates){
  dayy <- day(dates)
  suff <- case_when(dayy %in% c(11,12,13) ~ "th",
                    dayy %% 10 == 1 ~ 'st',
                    dayy %% 10 == 2 ~ 'nd',
                    dayy %% 10 == 3 ~'rd',
                    TRUE ~ "th")
  paste0(dayy, suff)
}

ads_so <- function(dates) {
  dayy <- day(dates)
  scales::ordinal(dayy)
}

dates <- as.Date(-1000:1000, now())
microbenchmark(ads_cw(dates), ads_so(dates))
## Unit: milliseconds
##           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
##  ads_cw(dates) 1.226038 1.267377 1.526139 1.329442 1.505056  3.180228   100  a 
##  ads_so(dates) 7.270987 7.632697 8.275644 8.077106 8.816440 10.571275   100   b
```

The answer code is still faster than `scales::ordinal` but the benchmark is now honest.

Of note, If you want to make a comparison using just numeric vectors, it is still ~ 7 times faster.

```
just_nums <- function(n){

  suff <- case_when(n %in% c(11,12,13) ~ "th",
                    n %% 10 == 1 ~ 'st',
                    n %% 10 == 2 ~ 'nd',
                    n %% 10 == 3 ~'rd',
                    TRUE ~ "th")
  paste0(n, suff)
}

microbenchmark(scales::ordinal(1:1000),
               just_nums(1:1000))

Unit: microseconds
                    expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
 scales::ordinal(1:1000) 4411.144 4483.191 5055.2170 4560.647 4738.355 45206.038   100
       just_nums(1:1000)  666.407  687.305  788.3066  713.319  746.347  1808.943   100
```

Comment: you may want to compare performance against `scales::ordinal`

Comment: @hrbrmstr -- seems pretty fast

Comment: while yours will still be faster, that's not a proper comparison

Answer (score 2):

`scales::ordinal` has been superseded by `scales::label_ordinal`.

```r
scales::label_ordinal()(as.integer(vec))
#   [1] "1st"  "2nd"  "3rd"  "4th"  "5th"  "6th"  "7th"  "8th"  "9th"  "10th" "11th" "12th" "13th" "14th" "15th"
#  [16] "16th" "17th" "18th" "19th" "20th" "21st" "22nd" "23rd" "24th" "25th" "26th" "27th" "28th" "29th" "30th"
#  [31] "31st" "1st"  "2nd"  "3rd"  "4th"  "5th"  "6th"  "7th"  "8th"  "9th"  "10th" "11th" "12th" "13th" "14th"
#  [46] "15th" "16th" "17th" "18th" "19th" "20th" "21st" "22nd" "23rd" "24th" "25th" "26th" "27th" "28th" "29th"
#  [61] "1st"  "2nd"  "3rd"  "4th"  "5th"  "6th"  "7th"  "8th"  "9th"  "10th" "11th" "12th" "13th" "14th" "15th"
#  [76] "16th" "17th" "18th" "19th" "20th" "21st" "22nd" "23rd" "24th" "25th" "26th" "27th" "28th" "29th" "30th"
#  [91] "31st" "1st"  "2nd"  "3rd"  "4th"  "5th"  "6th"  "7th"  "8th"  "9th"  "10th" "11th" "12th" "13th" "14th"
# [106] "15th" "16th" "17th" "18th" "19th" "20th" "21st" "22nd" "23rd" "24th" "25th" "26th" "27th" "28th" "29th"
# [121] "30th" "1st"  "2nd"  "3rd"  "4th"  "5th"  "6th"  "7th"  "8th"  "9th"  "10th" "11th" "12th" "13th" "14th"
# [136] "15th" "16th" "17th" "18th" "19th" "20th" "21st" "22nd" "23rd" "24th" "25th" "26th" "27th" "28th" "29th"
# [151] "30th" "31st" "1st"  "2nd"  "3rd"  "4th"  "5th"  "6th"  "7th"  "8th"  "9th"  "10th" "11th" "12th" "13th"
# [166] "14th" "15th" "16th" "17th" "18th" "19th" "20th" "21st" "22nd" "23rd" "24th" "25th" "26th" "27th" "28th"
# [181] "29th" "30th" "1st"  "2nd"  "3rd"  "4th"  "5th"  "6th"  "7th"  "8th"  "9th"  "10th" "11th" "12th" "13th"
# [196] "14th" "15th" "16th" "17th" "18th" "19th" "20th" "21st" "22nd" "23rd" "24th" "25th" "26th" "27th" "28th"
# [211] "29th" "30th" "31st" "1st"  "2nd"  "3rd"  "4th"  "5th"  "6th"  "7th"  "8th"  "9th"  "10th" "11th" "12th"
# [226] "13th" "14th" "15th" "16th" "17th" "18th" "19th" "20th" "21st" "22nd" "23rd" "24th" "25th" "26th" "27th"
# [241] "28th" "29th" "30th" "31st" "1st"  "2nd"  "3rd"  "4th"  "5th"  "6th"  "7th"  "8th"  "9th"  "10th" "11th"
# [256] "12th" "13th" "14th" "15th" "16th" "17th" "18th" "19th" "20th" "21st" "22nd" "23rd" "24th" "25th" "26th"
# [271] "27th" "28th" "29th" "30th" "1st"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little help:

```
getOrdinalNumber <- function(num) {
   result <- ""
  if (!(num %% 100 %in% c(11, 12, 13))) {
    result <- switch(as.character(num %% 10), 
                     "1" = {paste0(num, "st")}, 
                     "2" = {paste0(num, "nd")},
                     "3" = {paste0(num, "rd")},
                     paste0(num,"th"))
      } else {
        result <- paste0(num, "th")
      }
    result
}
```

The function works the following way:

`num %% 100` indicates x mod y, so you check the remainder after division of one number by another. So for example `21 %% 100` is 21. So 21 is NOT `%in% c(11,12,13)`, but `!` makes the statement `TRUE` and the `switch` argument adds a "st"

If we have `num <- 11`, the first check `11 %% 100` is 11 and so a "th" is added (so we are in the `else` loop)

That's just a starting point for you, because you can use this function to do this not only for single numbers, but for whole vectors.
But that's your work to do :-)

Comment: Perhaps the edits don't show up for some reason on my computer but I get 11st, 12nd, and 13rd. Prob because `c(11,12,13) %% 10 %in% c(1,2,3) == TRUE` for all 3.