# How can I get the middle date of three dates in R?

Tags: r, date

I have a datatable with three date columns x, y and z and I am trying to create a new column (new_col) that is the middle date of the three dates in each row once ranked from earliest to latest, i.e., I want the date between the min and max date – please see table below:

| x | y | z | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st Jan 2005 | 4th May 1998 | 2nd Mar 2009 | 1st Jan 2005 |
| 9th May 2010 | 14th Feb 2003 | 9th Jan 2008 | 9th Jan 2008 |
| 7th Sept 2002 | 8th Dec 2010 | 23rd May 2012 | 8th Dec 2010 |

So, for rows 1, 2, and 3 I would like the dates from column x, z, and y, respectively. How can I go about this in R? I have used pmin and pmax but I can't isolate the date in the middle

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! It's always better to have a copy/paste-able example in your post. That makes a quick answer much more likely. Something like `dput(mydata)` with output in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure all your dates are "Date" type, you can use `dmy` from `lubridate` for this (assumes your data frame is called `df`):

```
library(lubridate)

df[] <- lapply(df, dmy)
```

Next, sort each row in chronological order, and take the middle column (column 2) to be the `new_col`:

```
df$new_col <- as.Date(t(apply(df, 1, sort))[,2])
```

Finally, if you want the result to be displayed in same text format (e.g., "1st Jan 2005" instead of "2005-01-01") then you can use a custom function based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40041236/3460670):

```
library(dplyr)

date_to_text <- function(dates){
  dayy <- day(dates)
  suff <- case_when(dayy %in% c(11,12,13) ~ "th",
                    dayy %% 10 == 1 ~ 'st',
                    dayy %% 10 == 2 ~ 'nd',
                    dayy %% 10 == 3 ~'rd',
                    TRUE ~ "th")
  paste0(dayy, suff, " ", format(dates, "%b %Y"))
}

df[] <- lapply(df, date_to_text)
```

**Output**

```
             x             y             z      new_col
1 1st Jan 2005  4th May 1998  2nd Mar 2009 1st Jan 2005
2 9th May 2010 14th Feb 2003  9th Jan 2008 9th Jan 2008
3 7th Sep 2002  8th Dec 2010 23rd May 2012 8th Dec 2010
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(x = c("1st Jan 2005", "9th May 2010", "7th Sept 2002"
), y = c("4th May 1998", "14th Feb 2003", "8th Dec 2010"), z = c("2nd Mar 2009", 
"9th Jan 2008", "23rd May 2012")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach below

- coerces the character date strings to numeric type `Date` as there is no arithmetic with character dates,
- finds the position of the "middle" date in *each row*
- and returns the corresponding character string
- which eventually becomes `new_col`.

This can be implemented using `apply()` on each row using an appropriate function:

```
df$new_col <- apply(df, 1L, function(x) x[order(lubridate::dmy(x))][2L])
df
```

> ```
>               x             y             z      new_col
> 1  1st Jan 2005  4th May 1998  2nd Mar 2009 1st Jan 2005
> 2  9th May 2010 14th Feb 2003  9th Jan 2008 9th Jan 2008
> 3 7th Sept 2002  8th Dec 2010 23rd May 2012 8th Dec 2010
> ```

### Note

This returns the expected result. `new_col` is a character date string.

However, if the OP intends to continue working with type `Date`, e.g. doing more arithmetic, I recommend to follow [Ben's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66306364/3817004) and to coerce the whole data.frame to type `Date` and to stick to it.